# How is gitosis-serve invoked?

Tags: python, git

I have a working installation of Gitosis, but I'm wondering how the `gitosis-serve` command ever gets invoked! From all I can understand, when you connect through SSH as the `git` user (using `git@host`), the `serve.py` script gets invoked by the script generated by setuptools in `/usr/bin/gitosis-serve`, which then launches `git-shell`.

However, how is the `git` user's login connected to `/usr/bin/gitosis-serve`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/bazaar/2008q4/049927.html). Basically, the `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys` file (generated by `gitosis-init`) maps each registered key to the `gitosis-serve` command!

Comment: So basically what I had said :)

Comment: @JeremyBouse: if you look at the dates, you can see I answered before you did...

Answer (score 2):

When you add an SSH key to `gitosis-admin.git` repository it is automatically checked out during the commit and the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file for the gitosis user is updated to call `gitosis-serve` for the given SSH key. What repositories the user can actually manage is of course dependent on which repositories in the `gitosis.conf` that they have been given access.